# Sacar var de una funcion

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función. El problema que tengo es que no puedo sacar el var `c` del función `contains`. Entonces el `console.log(c)` que tengo en mi `if` no funciona. Como puedo cambiar `contains` para que funcione esto?

```
function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + target.includes(word);
  });
  var c = value;
  return (value === 1)
}

if (contains(a, b)) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(c);
} else {
  //false statement..do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a, c;
function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + target.includes(word);
  });
  c = value;
  return (value === 1)
}

if (contains(a, b)) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(c);
} else {
  //false statement..do nothing
}
```

Comment: No deberias dejar la pregunta con solo codigo. Aunque sea simple explica lo que has hecho para resolver su problema. Piensa que esta respuesta no es solo para el autor de la pregunta si no para quienes tengan un problema similar, van a mirar tu respuesta (ya que está marcada como la aceptada) Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Sacando la variable de la función:

```
var c = -1; //Aquí la declaras

function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + target.includes(word);
  });
  c = value;
  return (value === 1)
}

if (contains(a, b)) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(c);
} else {
  //false statement..do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías simplemente devolver `value` y comprobar que:

- Si es igual a uno (`1`) significa "lo contiene".
- Si es distinto de uno, "no lo contiene".

Ejemplo:

```js
function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + target.includes(word);
  });
  return value;
}

var a = ['a'];
var b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var c = contains(a, b);

if (c === 1) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(c);
} else {
  //false statement..do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias alternativas para poder hacer uso de la variable `c`. Algunas de ellas son estas:

Declarar la variable `c` fuera del contexto de la función, en un **ámbito más global**:

```
var c;

function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + target.includes(word);
  });
  c = value;
  return (value === 1)
}

if (contains(a, b)) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(c);
} else {
  //false statement..do nothing
}
```

**Devolver un objeto** con los dos valores necesitados:

```
function contains(target, pattern) {
  var value = 0;
  pattern.forEach(function(word) {
    value = value + target.includes(word);
  });

  return { c: value, contains: (value == 1) };
}

var result = contains(a, b); 
if (result.contains) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(result.c);
} else {
  //false statement..do nothing
}
```

Finalmente, simplemente implementarlo mediante **callbacks**.